# How to set the additional arguments of a new generic to be the same as their default values in the default method

Tags: r, generics, arguments, r-s3

When implementing a generic method for a new class:

```
scale.newclass <- function(x, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE) {
    ...
}
```

How to guarantee that the default values for additional arguments `center` and `scale` always stay consistent with their default values in `scale.default`?

In other words - if in the future `scale.default` changes it's default argument to `scale = FALSE`, how to make sure `scale.newclass` defaults are also adjusted to match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `scale.default` inherits the default values of its arguments from the generic function `scale`:

```r
identical(formals(scale), formals(scale.default))
## [1] TRUE
```

Those values will not change unless the generic function changes, and if the generic function changes, then you'll be warned about inconsistencies by `R CMD check`.  So the example doesn't quite motivate the problem ...

Setting that aside, you can do this programmatically with `formals<-`:

```r
formals(scale.a) <- formals(scale.default)
```

Well, that only works for generic functions not admitting a formal argument `...`:

```r
any(names(formals(scale)) == "...")
## [1] FALSE
```

In general, the formals of the two methods may not have the same length or the same names, and in that case you would want to be more careful:

```r
f <- function(x, ...) UseMethod("f")
f.default <- function(x, a = 1, b = 2, c = a + b, ...) x
f.a       <- function(x, a = 1, b = 1, c = a - b, ...) x

form.default <- formals(f.default)
form.a       <- formals(f.a)

nms <- intersect(names(form.default), names(form.a))
formals(f.a)[nms] <- form.default[nms]

identical(formals(f.a), form.default)
## [1] TRUE
```

Still, my feeling is that these kinds of "precautions" can cause more problems than they solve in the long run ...

Answer (score 1):

It seems very unlikely that those values would ever change, but if you are really worried about, you could do something like

```
scale.newclass <- function(x, center = formals(scale.default)$center, scale = formals(scale.default)$scale) {
    ...
}
```

That will read the default values from the function signature.